# How to use get_posts() function in functions.php

Tags: functions, ajax, get-posts

I am trying to load posts with ajax. But I am not getting any content of the posts. I am not posting my javascript since it is pretty straight.
Here is my code in inc/helper-functions.php which is included in main functions.php.

```
function get_my_posts(){

    $posts_per_page = $_POST['posts_per_page'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => $posts_per_page,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => $category,
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC'
    );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $myposts ) {

        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

    } else {
        echo 'Ingen innhold';
    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_posts", "get_my_posts");
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_posts', 'get_my_posts');
```

Here is how content.php looks like:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="meta">
        <?php the_time('d.m.Y') ?>
    </div>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php  the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>

    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

</article>
```

I am getting through the loop, but don't get the contents to be printed. None of the functions for ex. the_ID(), the_excerpt(),  post_class(), etc. don't work. If I use the same code in the template, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a global declaration of $post at the beginning of the function. Just like this:

```
function get_my_posts(){
    global $post;
    // rest of the code.
}
```

Original answer from stackoverflow: [xphan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33168428/431472)